# GitHub Pages absolute_url discrepancy

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I changed my GH Pages *Source* setting from "classic"/"hands off" to "GitHub Actions (Beta)", and after some tweaking, everything is working the same again, except for one thing: when hosted on **`my-subdomain.github.io`** the link to the home page goes to **`github.com`**.

The anchor tag comes from jekyll-theme-primer's [`default.html`](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) layout and looks like this:

```html
<a href="{{ "/" | absolute_url }}">
```

On my local machine (in Docker), this is fine and links to `localhost:3000` and previously on GH Pages it linked to `my-subdomain.github.io` (and I named the repository the same) which was fine, but after the switch it links to `github.com` which is bad.

My GHA workflow is a straight copy of [the official starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll.yml) which runs this command:

```
bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "${{ steps.pages.outputs.base_path }}"
```

And `site.base_url` is "" in all cases.

According to the Jekyll docs, `absolute_url` "prepends `url` and `base_url` to the input". Why is `url` set to `github.com` now and what's the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `_config-gh.yml` with `url` set to the correct github.io subdomain and adding `--config _config.yml,_config-gh.yml` to the workflow command.